# Cache query results

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql

Let's say, we have a highly configurable report system, which allows users to select columns, filters, and sorting.

All this configuration comes to BE, where it's being transformed to SQL, executed against DB and then the user sees his report and can continue to work with it. But on each operation, like sorting, we still build a query.

The transformation itself takes few milliseconds, but the query execution against DB can take 3-5 seconds (up to 20 if there are a lot of parallel executions).

So, I'm thinking about adding some sort of cache.

Currently, I see 3 ways:

1. Add one table to cache all results without filtering, and then on user request sort/filter it on Java side.
2. Add one table per result, still without the filters. In this case, I will have the possibility to sort/filter on much less amount of data, but there are more than 10k different reports, and I don't think it would be good to create 10k small tables.
3. Like the first option, but LRU cache on Java side. We can fit in memory 2-3k report results. It will be usually faster than in the first option since we don't have a lot of parallel users, just users with lots of reports.

The cache invalidation will be a few times a day.

What do you see is the best way to make it faster? What cons and pros in proposed solutions from yours perspective? What would you do if you are free in selecting Database and technology (Java stack)?

Comment: I think you need to write some code and come back with a more specific question. This question seems more relevant to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ . If you are using spring, then there is the @Cacheable annotation with spring-data.

Comment: Make sure your queries are optimized first of all.

Comment: Nothing of 1 2 3 - I would rather look at Spring caching https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/ and Hibernate Second Level Cache https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache

Comment: What's the point of using a database and then load all data in memory and reimplement the database sorting and filtering in Java? How could that be faster then native database query?

Comment: @Michal Spring and Hibernate will allow only to cache already performed query. The point of using sorting/filtering in Java is to avoid additional filtering on the DB side. In the DB table, I have 2b records, however, the user needs to sort/filter less than 1k.

Comment: What makes the queries slow? Is it sorts, or aggregates, or the filtering itself?... If it is aggregates, have you considered materialized views, like summary table by month? -- When you say the usual query returns less than 1k results, you want to use cache to do further sort/filter on the 1k results, correct?

Comment: I mean to avoid re-doing the costly query which yields the 1k results while still being able to sort/filter that to the user's whim? Is the 1k results completely fetched by your application (is the data size manageable or slow, like big blob columns?) and if not would it be costly to fetch it completely or not?

Comment: If your query always returns subset of same 1k data from 2b database then you simply need those 1k data as a table(s) in database.

Comment: If the question is that the user wants to sort and/or filter the subset of data he just queried then that could be done without new query. It depends on the client architecture how to best do that, e.g. doing it on the client itselfs or putting that in HttpSession for tradional web application. But I would not call that *cache*.

Comment: @peufeu there is no a lot of data in rows, just short strings, dates and integers. It’s not costly to fetch it in memory and even save there for a while.

Comment: @Michal I can’t split it by user, only by report, when it is generated. Also, user may request to get top 10 records, but the sorting should be on all records. It will be costly to create 10k tables in postgres, however I’m thinking to setup hive metastore on hdfs, there I can create all the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's make sure I got it right.

> there are more than 10k different reports

So it doesn't make sense to pre-calculate and pre-cache them, they have to be generated on-demand.

> there is not a lot of data in rows, just short strings, dates and integers. It’s not costly to fetch it in memory and even save there for a while

So caching a small amount of data can avoit a big costly query, that's good.

> Add one table to cache all results without filtering, and then on user request sort/filter it on Java side.

Problem is, most likely every report query will have different columns, with different names, so that doesn't fit a single table well unless you use a format like JSON, storing each cached result row as a JSON dictionary... And in this case indexing it would be a problem, even if you create indexes on fields inside JSON values, if you have a zillion different column names from your many reports you'll need a zillion indexes too...

Smells like a can of worms.

> Add one table per result, still without the filters. In this case, I will have the possibility to sort/filter on much less amount of data, but there are more than 10k different reports, and I don't think it would be good to create 10k small tables.

**Pros:** each cache table can have the proper columns, data types and indexes. It is easy to invalidate the cache, just truncate it. You can set all the cache tables to UNLOGGED to make them faster. And you can do all the extra sorting/filtering on the cached result using the same SQL queries you were using before, so this might be the simpler option to code. It is also nice for pagination if you only want to fetch part of the result. And that will be the fastest option as far as copying the results of reporting queries into cache since the cache is already in postgres, there is no need to transfer data. You can also store the cache on another drive/SSD.

Cons: I've heard the main issue with tons of tables is if your filesystem slows down on directories with large numbers of files. That shouldn't be an issue on modern filesystems though, and I don't think postgres itself is going to be bothered at all by 10k tables.

It might make queries on information_schema slow, and stuff like "\dt" in psql  problematic, so the cache tables would be better hidden away in a "cache" schema so they don't interfere. This will also make it easier to exclude them from backups.

It will also use some RAM on postgres server to cache the cache tables, that depends on the number of online users.

I'd say it would be worth a little bit of benchmarking. Create a schema, add 10k tables, see if something breaks.

> Like the first option, but LRU cache on Java side. We can fit in memory 2-3k report results. It will be usually faster than in the first option since we don't have a lot of parallel users, just users with lots of reports.

That's a bit of reinventing the wheel, and you got to reimplement the sort/filter in java... plus the cache algos... meeeh.

There are other options though:

- Put the cache in another database, on another machine. This may be a postgres instance, or another database (which may require rewriting some queries). Could be interesting only if the cache eats too much RAM on your database.
- Put the cache in the web browser, and use javascript to filter/sort. That could be faster depending on speed of internet connection, and it would reduce server load, but you'll have to write lots of javascript code.

IMO you're cautious about the large number of tables, it is good to be cautious, but if it works well, it really is the simplest solution...

Comment: It sounds reasonable to create different tables. The other option I'll try is to save everything in one table as JSONB and expand it to rows with 'jsonb_array_elements'. This will also allow to sort/filter on DB side.